# findViewById returns null in Listfragment

Tags: android

I am not able to access the textview `textinvite` within onActivityCreated() of my Listfragment class using `getListView().findViewById(R.id.invitetext)`. It returns null. What am i doing wrong? I have gone through a lot of posts on SO, but the answers don't work for me.

**PhoneContactsListFragment.java :**

```
public class PhoneContactsListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        PhoneContactsListFragment.OnContactsInteractionListener {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_contact_list);
...
}
```

**activity_phone_contact_list.xml :**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/phone_contact_list"
    android:name="com.example.proj.PhoneContactsListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**PhoneContactsListFragment.java :**

```
public class PhoneContactsListFragment extends ListFragment implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
}

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
      if(getListView().findViewById(R.id.textinvite)==null)Log.d("Faizal","can't find invitetext");
...
}

private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
...
 @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final View itemLayout =
                    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_contact_list_item, viewGroup, false);
...
return itemLayout;
}
```

**contact_list_fragment.xml :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              style="@style/ContactListView"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/no_contacts"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**phone_contact_list_item.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                style="@style/listViewActivatedStyle">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/listview_item_padding"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/listview_item_padding"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="26dp"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

              android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/listview_item_padding"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/listview_item_padding"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_above="@android:id/text2"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textinvite"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#FFFF0000"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:text="@string/invite"
              android:gravity="right"
              android:layout_gravity="right"
              android:visibility="gone"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **TextView** which id is **textinvite** is almost in **phone_contact_list_item**..And you have already trying to find the id of that TextView in **contact_list_fragment**..That's why.

Comment: in your ContactsAdapter

Comment: you are absolutely right! But my original intention was to create an onclickListener on textinvite. So, if i register the onclickListener inside newView(), it will be registered 10 times since there are 10 visible items and newView() will be called every time. Any idea where i should be ideally registering the onclickListener to avoid this?

Comment: you can call setOnItemClick Listner on ListView.

Comment: thanks, but listview.setOnItemClickListener apparently listens to only clicks on the list items, but not the textinvite(which is a child inside the listview item). When i click on textinvite, nothing happens. If i click anywhere outside textinvite, the onItemClickListener is triggered. I was looking for a click listener at a more granular level. textinvite was clickable when i had implemented the onClickListener on textinvite inside newView().

Answer (score 1):

The `R.id.textinvite` exists **inside** `R.layout phone_contact_list_item` not inside `R.layout.contact_list_fragment`.

Comment: yes, but i get null even if i use getListView().findViewById(android.R.id.list).findViewById(R.id.textinvite). Or is that the wrong way to access?

Comment: Certainly is wrong way because you are trying to access something that not exist

Comment: Sorry, what does not exist? My fragment layout has "list" and the item layout has "textinvite".

Comment: From what I see try to reverse the order of 'R.layout phone_contact_list_item' with 'R.layout.contact_list_fragment'. I think here is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
  @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);


  .....getListView().findViewById(R.id.textinvite).....
 return rootView;
   }
```

Comment: That fails with error "Unable to start activity".."error inflating class fragment".."content view not yet created". getListView() itself throws the exception